# Fetching 2 columns from Tuple using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a tuple which looks like this when I iterate through its rows:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
        print(row)
```

o/p :

```
(100214, '120.6843686', '-41.9098438')
(101105, '121.7692179', '-42.2737880')
(101847, '122.6417215', '-43.8718865')
```

Output Desired:

```
('120.6843686', '-41.9098438')
('121.7692179', '-42.2737880')
('122.6417215', '-43.8718865')
```

I am new to Python, so any help would really be appreciated. 
Thanks..

Comment: Learn about Python's slicing syntax. `row[1:]`

Comment: Slicing would give you result desired here, but you could also consider just iterating over the subset of your DataFrame that you actually want to look at by referencing specific columns: `for row in df[['col1', 'col2']].itertuples(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
        print(row[1:])
```

This slices the tuple and displays everything after column 0. This [article](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) explains it in further detail if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get values here's a simple way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame((
    (100214, '120.6843686', '-41.9098438'),
    (101105, '121.7692179', '-42.2737880'),
    (101847, '122.6417215', '-43.8718865'))
)

df = df.iloc[:, 1:].values.tolist()
print(df)
```

```
[['120.6843686', '-41.9098438'],
 ['121.7692179', '-42.2737880'],
 ['122.6417215', '-43.8718865']]
```